Why doesn't HTML parsing ignore script tags with text/plain MIME type?
According to MDN, a script tag with MIME type text/plain "won't be processed by the browser".
But in my tests, when I try to inline a lot of data (like 150MB of 3D points) into a script tag like below, it is indeed parsed by the browser on opening the HTML file.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test OBJ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/plain">
        // 150MB worth of data
    </script>
    <h3>This title will show several seconds after opening the HTML file</h3>
</body>
</html>

I have to create HTML files that contain everything they need inline, including CSS, scripts, and huge amount of data. These files are opened locally by users. Is there a way to make the browser ignore data blocks during HTML parsing ?
I tried several MIME types in the type attribute.
I tried running performance tests in Chrome devtool to see what is blocking, and every time it seems to be HTML parsing:

Edit: These files are opened locally and off network.

It has to parse the contents in order to find the </script> tag, of course.  If you're worried about it, send the page without the huge data block and use an AJAX request to fetch it after loading.

"won't be processed" means it won't execute it as a script. It still has to generate the DOM structure.

OP says "These files are opened locally by users" so the suggested use of AJAX/fetch is not a viable solution unless OP moves to a server.

@StephenP since it is the browser that is doing the parsing, I think that onload, the browser should take that opportunity to fetch() the data block and populate that script tag after which the user will now have the complete HTML. There is no way around the network bandwidth though. This is just my two cents. This will make good UX while the other heavy lifting is done by the server in the background.

They are opened off network but are they received over the network?

If type attribute is any other value that is not:

"" (empty string)
A valid Javascript MIME type
importmap
module

The embedded content is treated as a data block, and won't be processed by the browser.
Nonetheless the client receives this HTML as is over the network (which is a lot of bandwidth if you think about it).
The Parser streams through the HTML to build a valid DOMTree. It must stream through the HTML by running through characters one by one which means it will run through all <s, >s, </s e.t.c. It has to stream through to know what the DOM will look like. But when it gets to such script tags, the browser won’t interpret that section as Javascript that’s all.
I will have to recommend what has already been mentioned in the comments. fetch() that data separately in such a way that it will not affect the GUI. fetch() it asynchronously.

Thank you for your input. The part of your answer related to bandwidth and fetch is irrelevant though, as I mentioned in my question these files are only used locally and must contain everything inline in a single HTML file. Do you know a way to have a browser ignore the content of a data block during parsing ?

The whole parsing process is to build a DOMTree. If you don’t want to show this file in the DOM, then there is no need for parsing to begin with. But if you want to show it in the DOM then that script tag is doing nothing there.

@felixmariotto — Thought experiment — forget your HTML, the browser, and bandwidth for a minute and think about this problem: You need to write code to read a plain text file but skip everything beginning with the text [ignore] up to finding [/ignore], and output the rest of the file not including that ignored block. Q: How are you going to find the [/ignore] to discover where the ignored block ends? ... Even though you're going to ignore that block you must still read the block to find where it ends. This is what Chukwujiobi is explaining in terms of the browser, even if it's local.
